# Residue of $\frac{\pi\cot({\pi z})}{(1+z^2)^2}$ at $z=\pm i$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Calculate the residue of $f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot({\pi z})}{(1+z^2)^2}$ at $z=\pm i$.

So far this is what I have for the residue at $z=i$:

\begin{align}
\text{Res} (f(z),i)&=\lim_{z\to i} \frac{(z-i)\pi\cot({\pi z})}{(1+z^2)^2} =\lim_{z\to i} \frac{(z-i)\pi\cot({\pi z})}{((z+i)(z-i))^2}\\
&=\lim_{z\to i} \frac{(z-i)\pi\cot({\pi z})}{(z+i)(z-i)}  \cdot\lim_{z\to i} \frac{1}{1+z^2} \\
\text{Res} (f(z),i)&= \frac{-\pi\coth(\pi)}{2} \cdot\lim_{z\to i} \frac{1}{1+z^2}.
\end{align}

I checked my answer with [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=186fb23a33995d91ce3c2212189178c8) wolfram widget and the answer seems to be

$$-\frac{\pi}{4}\text{csch}(\pi)(\cosh(\pi)+\text{csch}(\pi))$$
which would mean I did something wrong at some point?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the formula you have used is for a simple pole (pole of order one). the function you have has $z=i$ as a pole of order 2. So the formula for the residue is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the limit $\lim_{z\to i}\frac1{z^2+1}$ does not exist, your answer doesn't make sense.

Let $f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+i)^2}$. Then $f(i)=\frac14\pi\coth(\pi)i$, and $f'(i)=-\frac{1}{4}\pi\left(\coth (\pi )+\pi\operatorname{csch}^2(\pi)\right)$. So\begin{align}\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z^2+1)^2}&=\frac{f(z)}{(z-i)^2}\\&=\frac{\pi\coth(\pi)i}{4(z-i)^2}-\frac{\pi\left(\coth (\pi )+\pi\operatorname{csch}^2(\pi)\right)}{4(z-i)}+\cdots,\end{align}and therefore$$\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\left(\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\right)=-\frac{1}{4}\pi\left(\coth (\pi )+\pi\operatorname{csch}^2(\pi)\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.